# Polymer on tap event, how do I pick it up in my template

Tags: data-binding, polymer-1.0

I built a small test page to try and explore a dialog.  I have a paper button to do an action on the dialog, but I am failing to get the linkage between the tap event and the function it should have called.  I am getting this error message.

```
[dom-bind::_createEventHandler]: listener method `{{handleTap}}` not defined
```

Here is the code

```
      <template is="dom-bind" id="app">
      <paper-dialog id="logon-dialog"
        modal
        entry-animation="scale-up-animation"
        exit-animation="fade-out-animation"
        opened
      >
        <h2>User Login</h2>
        <iron-a11y-keys keys="Enter" on-keys-pressed="{{doLogon}}"></iron-a11y-keys>
        <form id="dologon" is="iron-form" action="/serve/logon.php" method="POST" contentType="application/json">
          <paper-input label="User Name" ></paper-input>
          <paper-input label="password" type="password"></paper-input>
          <paper-checkbox>Edit Profile after Log On</paper-checkbox>
        </form>
        <div class="buttons">
          <paper-button raised on-tap="{{handleTap}}">Log On</paper-button>
        </div>
      </paper-dialog>


    <paper-header-panel class="flex">
      <paper-toolbar><div ident>PASv5</div><span class="flex"></span><iron-icon icon="menu:calendar"></iron-icon><iron-icon icon="search"></iron-icon><iron-icon icon="menu"></iron-icon><span>User Name</span></paper-toolbar>
      <div></div>
    </paper-header-panel>
  </template>
 <script>
    var app= document.querySelector("#app");
    app.handleTap = function(event) {
      this.$.logon-dialog.close();
    };
</script>
```

How do I define a function that can be called from on-tap?

The error message implies I should be adding an event listener.  Is this necessary as it seems more complicated.  If it is how do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to remove the binding braces on your handler:

```
<paper-button raised on-tap="handleTap">Log On</paper-button>
```

See [annotated event listener setup](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events.html#annotated-listeners) for more info.

Comment: Thanks, was looking for that documentation and couldn't find it.  Fixes the problem for on-tap.  I changed the iron-a11y-keys to call handleTap also, but it doesn't seem to be being called.  I need to spend more time with it before giving up (and asking another question here) though.

Comment: my iron-a11y-keys problems was just that I wasn't importing it through using the wrong file.  So irrelevant to this discussion